# the_widget() inside functions.php

Tags: functions, widgets

I'm setting some options in the backend using functions.php and I'm doing:

```
$w = the_widget('My_Custom_Widget');
```

but I don't get any output.

However doing

```
<?php the_widget('My_Custom_Widget'); ?>
```

on any page template works fine.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The function `the_widget()` does not return any output it only `echo`s it. If you want to save its output to a variable you need to use output buffering.

```
ob_start();
the_widget('My_Custom_Widget');
$w = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```